# How to create .txt file with value and current path where this file is save in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to create .txt file in Python I have code like below:

```
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("XYZ")
```

And as a result I have .txt file with value: `XYZ`

But I need to create .txt file with values like below, so XYZ and path whete this file is created:

```
XYZ
Path: "C:\Users\John\Desktop\projects\readme.txt"
```

How can I modify my code where I create this file so as to have as a result values presented above?

Comment: are you looking for something like __file__? where it will give the path to the current file?

Comment: or how to save the file to "C:\Users\John\Desktop\projects\readme.txt"?

Comment: I need to have i my .txt file value "XYZ" and path where this file is saved, but I do not know how to write code which will return path to this file in this file, how can I do that ?

Comment: you want the current working directory (cwd). the os modal has a function for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the cwd

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("XYZ")
    f.write('\nPath: "'+os.getcwd()+'\\readme.txt"')
```

Comment: ellie, one more question how can I add also current date and time ? to this .txt file

Comment: yes, look in to https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html, you should have enough information to make it work